# Prometheus alertmanager to send alerts based on alertname to relevant receivers

Tags: routes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Here is the alertmanager.yml file I have, it has 2 routes with routing taken care via alertname winA and winB. I am able to get alerts from winA to winA receiver but for some reason when I try to generate alerts from winB it is been sent to default receiver and not by winB receiver. What could be issue not seeing any errors. Also able to see alerts with the alertname.

Also verified alertule.yml has correct alertnames as winA and winB

My plan is to direct alerts of winA(serverA) to TeamA respectively..

Checked alerts and can see alertnames are correct and even checked yml they are all good

Alertmanager.yml:

```yaml
route:
  group_by: ['alertname', 'instance']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 30m
  receiver: 'default'  

  routes:
    - receiver: 'winA'
      match_re:
        alertname: winA
    - receiver: 'winB'
      match_re:
        alertname: winB

receivers:
  - name: 'winA'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'A@A.com'
        send_resolved: true
        from: 'fromA@A.com'
  - name: 'winB'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'B@B.com'
        send_resolved: true
        from: 'fromB@B.com'
  - name: 'default'
```

Comment: route:
  group_by: ['alertname', 'instance']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 30m
  receiver: 'default'  # Default receiver for unmatched alerts

  routes:
    - receiver: 'winA'
      match_re:
        alertname: winA
    - receiver: 'winB'
      match_re:
        alertname: winB

receivers:
  - name: 'winA'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'A@A.com'
        send_resolved: true
        from: 'fromA@A.com'
  - name: 'winB'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'B@B.com'
        send_resolved: true
        from: 'fromB@B.com'
  - name: 'default'

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, check tips for fomatting posts [here](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: This tool: https://www.prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/, shows alerts properly addressed. Please double check alertnames in use. Also, [`match_re` is deprecated](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route); consider using `matchers` instead.

Comment: And finally, questions about configuration are offtopic for SO. But this question might be ontopic for [su].

Comment: thank you for formating yaml file, will make sure not to upload images and providing suggestions and routing tree editor @markalex i will try matchers and update